# Issues with URL conf in Django

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

So I'm working on a project that displays titles of and songs and albums released by a particular artiste from a database. I'm kinda stuck. I'm trying to create a page that displays the songs in an album when you click on the album link. When the link is clicked, I want the URL to display the name of the artiste and the title of the album but i keep getting served with the same error. It is matching the name of the album with artiste names.

How do I make the page display the songs in the album.

[image: Money]

*Here's the codes for views*

```
 def home(request):
    artistes = Artiste.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'music/home.html', locals())


 def details(request, artiste):
    artistes = get_object_or_404(Artiste, name=artiste)
    album = Artiste.objects.get(name=artiste).album_set.all()
    single = Artiste.objects.get(name=artiste).song_set.filter(single=True)
    return render(request, 'music/details.html', {'artistes': artistes, 'single': single, 'album':album})


def album_details(request,name,album):
    albums = get_object_or_404(Album, title=album)
    artistes = get_object_or_404(Artiste, name=name)
    single = Album.objects.get(title=album).song_set.filter(single=False)
     return render(request, 'music/album_detail.html', {'albums': albums, 'single': single})
```

*url patterns*

```
app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<artiste>.+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
    url(r'^(?P<name>.+)/(?P<album>.+)/$', views.album_details, name='album_details')
]
```

*album details page*

```
<body>
    {% if artistes.album_set.all %}
        {% for songs in album %}
            <h4>Albums</h4>
            <!--<img src="{{album.art}}"><br>
            -->
            <a href="{% url 'music:album_details' songs.artiste songs.title %}">{{songs.title}}</a>
            <h5>{{songs.artiste}}</h5>
            <h5>{{songs.title}}</h5>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
         <h3>No albums available</h3>
         <h5>Check Out Songs </h5>
        <ul>
        {% for song in artistes.song_set.all %}
            <li>{{song}} - mp3</li>
        {% endfor %}
         </ul>
    {% endif %}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is caued by: albums = get_object_or_404(Album, title=album)  not in URL.

Comment: @Zartch how do i rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs are too generic. `.+` matches *everything*, including things like "Wizked/Starboy" which you intended to be caught by the album_details URL.

You can fix this by switching the order of those URL patterns, but you should also make them less generic - eg `r'^(?P<artiste>\w+)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems OK. Is a Logical problem.

The error is: No artiste maching this query.

in the URLS, the matched url is:

> url(r'^(?P< artiste >.+)/$', views.details, name='details'),

**Why?** becouse ".+" matches everything, including "Wizkid/Starboy"

When you arrive to this code:

```
 albums = get_object_or_404(Album, title=album)
```

album is equals to "Wizkid/Starboy"

The query raises a 404 becouse no item was found.

if you change in the url the ".+" with "\w+"  as Daniel Said the match would be:

> url(r'^(?P< name>.+)/(?P< album>.+)/$', views.album_details, name='album_details')

Then the params would be:

name = Wizkid

album = Starboy

Then you execute the code:

```
albums = get_object_or_404(Album, title=album)
artistes = get_object_or_404(Artiste, name=name)
```

If there are records in the database with albums and artists with that name, the page shows up.
Is not you still have the 404.

I suggest you to change at least the albums query to:

```
albums = Album.objects.filter(title=album)
```

In the html you can do:

```
    {% for songs in album %}
            <h4>Albums</h4>
            <!--<img src="{{album.art}}"><br>
            -->
            <a href="{% url 'music:album_details' songs.artiste songs.title %}">{{songs.title}}</a>
            <h5>{{songs.artiste}}</h5>
            <h5>{{songs.title}}</h5>
        {% empty %}
             No album was found
        {% endfor %}
```

This way you can have a page with an artist with no albums

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. You're a hero bruh. Thanks. I've been on this for a loong time. Bless

Comment: I would prefer the correct answer instead the heroic words. But thx man. You are welcome. 
Keep coding.